# PHP Permalink not working

Tags: php, permalinks

I would like to create permalink for my url. So I have added .htaccess file to my root but it does not change.

vid is post id and id is page index. Thanks.

http://www.yatha.tv/play.php?vid=954&id=2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /play.php?vid=$1&id=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You _did_ enable interpretation of `.htaccess` style files for your http server? If not, please check the excellent documentation, I suggest.

Comment: Double check the `AllowOverride` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Apache module.

To activate the module, the following line in `httpd.conf` needs to be active:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

To see whether it is already active, try putting a `.htaccess` file into a web directory containing the line:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

if this works without throwing a 500 internal server error, and the `.htaccess` file gets parsed, URL rewriting works.